# Adjust system volume with trackbar control in vb

Tags: vb.net, volume, trackbar

Is it possible to control the system volume with a trackbar control in VB.NET?

When the user adjusts the value of the trackbar the system's volume will change too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Google gives you 3/4 of a million hits when you query "vb.net change system volume".  We don't need another one.

Comment: at least [see this](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=vb.net+change+system+volume&oq=vb.net+change+system+volume&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.221j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Control Volume in vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753009/control-volume-in-vb-net)

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer on the link @dude supplied. Thanks.

Imports System
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
    Partial Public Class Form1
        Inherits Form
        Private Const APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE As Integer = &H80000
        Private Const APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP As Integer = &HA0000
        Private Const APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN As Integer = &H90000
        Private Const WM_APPCOMMAND As Integer = &H319

```
    <DllImport("user32.dll")> _
    Public Shared Function SendMessageW(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, _
           ByVal Msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, _
           ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function

    Private Sub btnMute_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        SendMessageW(Me.Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, _
                      Me.Handle, New IntPtr(APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE))
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDecVol_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        SendMessageW(Me.Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, _
                     Me.Handle, New IntPtr(APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN))
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnIncVol_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        SendMessageW(Me.Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, _
                     Me.Handle, New IntPtr(APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP))
    End Sub
End Class
```

End Namespace